# Geth stuck syncing on the last 80 blocks

Tags: ethereum, geth

On Windows 10, on my command prompt, I go

`> geth --rinkeby`

Which start to sync my node with the network

On another command prompt, I go

`> geth --rinkeby attach ipc:\\.\pipe\geth.ipc`

And then

`> eth.syncing`

which gives

```
{

currentBlock: 3500871,

highestBlock: 3500955,

knownStates: 25708160,

pulledStates: 25680474,

startingBlock: 3500738

}
```

As you can see, I am always behind from the highest block by about 80. I've heard this is normal for the testnet. I created an account on Rinkeby and requested ether via the faucet: https://faucet.rinkeby.io/. I also tried https://faucet.ropsten.be/ but can't get ether.

On the geth console, I can show my account which gives

```
> eth.accounts

["0x7bf0a466e7087c4d40211c0fa8aaf3011176b6c6"]
```

and viewing the balance I get:

```
eth.getBalance(eth.accounts[0])
```

I don't know if this is due to my node being 80 blocks behind the highest node...?

Edit: It may be worth adding that I created a symbolic link from my AppData/Roaming/Ethereum on my C drive to another folder on my D drive as I was running out of space. (Don't know if that effects my sync)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you faced with a problem known as "not sync last 65 blocks"

> Q: I'm stuck at 64 blocks behind mainnet?!
>
> A: As explained above, you are not stuck, just finished with the block
>   download phase, waiting for the state download phase to complete too.
>   This latter phase nowadays take a lot longer than just getting the
>   blocks.

For more information https://github.com/ethereum/mist/issues/3760#issuecomment-390892894

Comment: Yes, I just thought that it was "stuck" as I would rapidly sync the first several million blocks before lagging behind. I just let it sync for several hours before it finished

Answer (score 0):

Stop the geth and start again. It’s pretty normal to be behind the highest block. For ether, check on etherscan once if you actually received the ether from the faucet or not. That way you will know on what block height you have received your either from faucet. Then wait till your geth sync till that block. Also the best option would be to use something like [Quicknode](https://quiknode.io/) where you don’t need to be concerned of always keeping your machine running or waiting for hours before continuing with Development work. Yes they have a small nominal fee, but for the service they provide it’s pretty worth it.